# Ruby on Rails - PostgreSQL Grouping error when doing joins & group

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join, grouping

In my application I have models `Visit` & `Post`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visits

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
```

Im trying to get all `visits` a `post` has in `visits` table. I did:

```
- a = Visit.joins(:post).group(:post_id).select(:post_id, :title, 'count(visits.id) as total_views').where(user: current_user)

- a.each do |a|
  %tr
    %td= a.title
    %td= a.total_views
```

This works find in my development env/localhost *(I think since I use `sqlite3`)*, butI am using **PostgreSql** in my production and I got this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ECT count(visits.id) as total_views, "visits"."post_id", "title", c...
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As the answer says `"posts.title" must appear in the GROUP BY`. In `group` add `:title` along with `:post_id`

```
Visit.joins(:post).group([:post_id, :title]).select('sum(cpc_bid) as earnings', :post_id, :title, 'count(visits.id) as total_views').where(influencer: current_user)
```